# How can I prevent fixtures with isSensor = true from passing through ground fixture?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am creating a border around the view-able area. Within this area I am creating other fixtures which are sensor enabled for collision detection. It seems that fixtures with isSensor = true pass through the window border. How can I prevent this from happening? Thanks!

```
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.Set(p.x/PTM_RATIO, p.y/PTM_RATIO);
    b2Body *body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    // Define another box shape for our dynamic body.
    b2PolygonShape dynamicBox;
    dynamicBox.SetAsBox(.5f, .5f);//These are mid points for our 1m box

    // Define the dynamic body fixture.
    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &dynamicBox; 
    fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.3f;
    fixtureDef.isSensor = true; //causes fixtures to fall through border
    body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
```

Window border:

```
 CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
 float widthInMeters = screenSize.width / PTM_RATIO;
 float heightInMeters = screenSize.height / PTM_RATIO;
 b2Vec2 lowerLeftCorner = b2Vec2(0, 0);
 b2Vec2 lowerRightCorner = b2Vec2(widthInMeters, 0);
 b2Vec2 upperLeftCorner = b2Vec2(0, heightInMeters);
 b2Vec2 upperRightCorner = b2Vec2(widthInMeters, heightInMeters);

b2BodyDef screenBorderDef;
screenBorderDef.position.Set(0, 0);
b2Body* screenBorderBody = world->CreateBody(&screenBorderDef);
b2EdgeShape screenBorderShape;

screenBorderShape.Set(lowerLeftCorner, lowerRightCorner);
screenBorderBody->CreateFixture(&screenBorderShape, 0);
screenBorderShape.Set(lowerRightCorner, upperRightCorner);
screenBorderBody->CreateFixture(&screenBorderShape, 0);
screenBorderShape.Set(upperRightCorner, upperLeftCorner);
screenBorderBody->CreateFixture(&screenBorderShape, 0);
screenBorderShape.Set(upperLeftCorner, lowerLeftCorner);
screenBorderBody->CreateFixture(&screenBorderShape, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to add a second fixture to the body that has the sensor on it, and set the collision filter so that it only collides with the border. You will need to learn a bit about how collision filter settings are used, and it can be a bit tricky at first. This might be helpful: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-filtering

By default the category bits value is 1, so unless you have changed anything, all fixtures in your scene have category 1. To differentiate between the border and other fixtures, you would have to give them different categories. Let's say you make the ground fixture category 2:

```
screenBorderFixtureDef.filter.categoryBits = 2;
```

The default value for mask is 0xFFFF so all of the existing fixtures will still collide with the border as before, even when the category is changed like this. Then to make the newly added second fixture ignore all but the borders, you would set the mask to only collide with the borders:

```
fixtureDef.filter.maskBits = 2;
```

---

Another way would be to make the existing sensor fixture not a sensor, to have it collide with the borders. But of course then it will also collide with everything else. You can use the PreSolve callback of the contact listener to say that certain contacts should not do any collision response:

```
//in PreSolve
if ( this is NOT a contact between border and sensor )
    contact->SetEnabled( false );
```

Comment: I'll check out Collision filtering. Thanks. Is it because my border fixtures and my other fixtures have the same category that they "pass through"? I am using b2EdgeShape to create the border fixtures. How would I set b2FixtureDef flags for the border? I would need to create the border with b2FixtureDef(s) rather than b2EdgeShape?

Comment: Sensor fixtures will always pass through everything all the time, that's how they work. Yes, you'll have to use a b2FixtureDef when creating the border, the same way as you have for the dynamic body in the first part of the code you posted, where you set friction etc.

Answer (score 1):

Make it isSensore false and check collision in the PostCollision method